# autohotkey script to bind multiple key-presses to one key

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

> ^y::
>   y
>   + & 6
>   return

**On pressing control+Y I want the actions of:

y^6

to be pressed on the keyboard.**
The above doesn't work. I can't find where it says in any documentation or tutorial how to make this work. I want the solution in simplest terms possible, explain what each callup command does.

Comment: "autohotkey"; with y^6 I meant it to literally press the keys that would otherwise type those words out on the screen.

Comment: Send only types out text. i need key-presses. So if I was in a game or program and certain keys did certain things I need those keys to all chain together with the single press of (control+y) i.e. "^y". To do operations. In one instance I want this for a game. Pressing y in the game is the hotkey for chat. ^6 while chat is open will do a coloured text operation. So the intent is for the keybind in autohotkeys, that upon hitting "ctrl y" I'd want to open the chat box and initiate the coloured text command.

Comment: i just want the keypress in general. all they have available is that send thing, and send only outputs text not keypreses. I want to know the commands to output more than 1 keypress...anywhere. The simply command for making 1 key = another is there....what's the command to chain them so 1 key = 2??